# How to dynamically add views to a scrollview in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an app where there is a ScrollView taking up part of a screen, and I've added a linearlayout within that, but I need to dynamically add rows of views (a textView, 2 editText views, and a checkbox on each row) and be able to pull data from those to be put into a database.

I'm pretty new to Android development, so I'm really not sure how to go about doing this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use a ListView instead of a ScrollView, and dymanically add/remove elements.

Once you learn about ListView you'll find how to do this quite easy:

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Comment: This was helpful thanks! I might have to use a ListView or GridView to do what I want instead.

Answer (score 3):

Create this layout xml (arrange the way you want) say `item_layout`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText2" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New CheckBox"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Adding views**

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
      (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout scrollViewLinearlayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.scroll_view_linear_layout); // The layout inside scroll view
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    LinearLayout layout2 = new LinearLayout(context);
    layout2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null, false);
    layout2.setId(i);
    layout2.addView(item);
    scrollViewLinearlayout.addView(layout2);    
}
```

**Getting values from the view**

```
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    LinearLayout itemLl = (LinearLayout)scrollViewLinearlayout.findViewById(i);
    EditText et1 = (EditText)itemLl.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String et1Str = et1.getText().toString();
    // Similarly get other values and add them in the database
}
```

Comment: how can you access layout2 from outside the block of for loop?scrollViewLl .addView(layout2)

Comment: further scrollViewLl .addView(layout2) should be inside loop right?

Comment: I think you also need to change type of scrollViewLl  to ScrollView.Thats what the user intend to do.

Comment: No. `scrollViewLl` is the linear layout inside the scroll view. You can't have more than one child in a scrollview. Thats why this linear layout is used.

Comment: Ok. but try to use meaningfull names such as wrappers instead of scrollview1.

Comment: Its `scrollViewLl` not `scrollview1`. I am just giving OP an idea of how to do that. I am not here to write code for anyone. Also I think my comment on that line was clear enough. Anyways I have changed the name.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful, but I was trying to have the 4 views go across as one row, and then add multiple rows dynamically with those same 4 views on each row. Any idea how to do that? I tried implementing the above code and messing around with it, but I don't think it's possible with a Linear Layout to do what I wanted.

Comment: Use GridView for that.

Comment: Yeah, I think i'll look in to that. Thanks for your help though!